# How to pass multiple values in parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2017

In this stored procedure, I need to pass multiple parameter values in `@GDNNO`. Right now I can pass only a single value.

Please help me.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.xspSHEGONPrintQuery4
    @GDNNO varchar(4000) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        a.ID, a.[To], a.FlowCode, a.TranNum, a.Status,
        ART.ARTICLECODE, StockGDNID, DetailID, SubDocCode, ArticleID,
        ColorCode, ColorName, SizeCode, SizeName,
        DispatchedUnits  * (CASE WHEN u.value IS NULL THEN FreezeStoringUOM ELSE u.value END) AS DispatchedUnits
    FROM
        xtstockgdn a (nolock)
    JOIN
        xtstockgdndetail b (nolock) ON a.id = b.stockgdnid
    JOIN 
        XTARTICLE ART (nolock) ON ART.ID = B.ARTICLEID
    LEFT JOIN
        xtUOMConversion u (nolock) ON u.FromUOM = art.StoringUOM
                                   AND u.ToUOM = art.consuom
    WHERE 
        a.ID IN (@GDNNO) 
        AND FlowCode = 'POO_RET[E-]'
END
```

Comment: Procedural code is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: If this is for SQL Server, the **proper** way to do this is to use a [table-valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters) for your stored procedure

Comment: its sql-server 2017

Answer (score 0):

Since your query is only `Select` it can be change to `TVF(table-value function)`. Change your Procedure  to TVF

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.xspSHEGONPrintQuery4(
    @GDNNO varchar(4000) = ''
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT
        a.ID, a.[To], a.FlowCode, a.TranNum, a.Status,
        ART.ARTICLECODE, StockGDNID, DetailID, SubDocCode, ArticleID,
        ColorCode, ColorName, SizeCode, SizeName,
        DispatchedUnits  * (CASE WHEN u.value IS NULL THEN FreezeStoringUOM ELSE u.value END) AS DispatchedUnits
    FROM
        xtstockgdn a (nolock)
    JOIN
        xtstockgdndetail b (nolock) ON a.id = b.stockgdnid
    JOIN 
        XTARTICLE ART (nolock) ON ART.ID = B.ARTICLEID
    LEFT JOIN
        xtUOMConversion u (nolock) ON u.FromUOM = art.StoringUOM
                                   AND u.ToUOM = art.consuom
    WHERE 
        a.ID IN (@GDNNO) 
        AND FlowCode = 'POO_RET[E-]'
END
```

Then use `Cross apply` to your `TVF`

```
Select a.GDNNO,b.* from yourtable a /*list of GDNNO Values */
Cross Apply dbo.xspSHEGONPrintQuery4(a.GDNNO) b
```

you can use `Dynamic query` as well